# Executing a network request every X seconds, how to pause/resume?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android, retrofit2

Previously, I was using a `Runnable` with a `Handler`, and executing `.postDelayed(runnable, delay)` with a delay of 3 seconds, to send a network request to an api, to update coordinates on a map. I thought this was a great opportunity to try and get some Rx in. I switched the Retrofit call to return an `Observable`, and use the `.interval()` operator to implement the repeated calls. Heres my current code:

```
Observable.interval(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<IssResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<IssResponse> call(Long aLong) {
                    Log.d("api", "inside the call method: " + aLong.toString());
                    return issService.getLocation();
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<IssResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("api", "rx comleted");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(IssResponse issResponse) {
                    Log.d("api", "response: " + issResponse.getIssPosition().getLatitude().toString());
                }
            });
```

This seems to function as expected, and returns a result every 3 seconds. Now what I would like to do, is "pause" and then afterwards resume these requests, as with the Android lifecycle, I dont want to keep executing requests if the user switches to a different fragment so that the map isnt even visible.

With the `Handler` and `Runnable`, I figured I could call `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)` in the `onPause()` method, which seemed to work alright for pausing the requests. I didnt get around to implementing the resume functionality using the `Handler` and `Runnable` method as I decided to switch to Rx. So how could this functionality be implemented with Rx? How could I pause and later resume the requests using RxJava?

**EDIT:** found a way to pause using `Observable.takeWhile(boolean)` and toggling the boolean. Now I just need a way to resume..

Answer (score 3):

As your `Observable` is not `hot` I would suggest you alternative and more simpler method: just subscribe and unsubscribe from your `Observable`.

Create your `Observable` inside `onCreate` of your `fragment`/`activity`/`presenter` and save reference:

```
private Observable<IssResponse> observable;
observable = Observable
        .interval(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<IssResponse>>() {
            //...
        });
```

In `onResume` subscribe and save reference to `Subscription`:

```
private Subscription subscription;
subscription = observable.subscribe(result -> {
    //user your data
});
```

And finally unsubscribe in `onPause`/`onStop`:

```
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Also there is [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle) library, I don't use it so I'm not sure that it fits your requirement with `interval`.

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing. I'm actually using a Google MapFragment, so I have an `onMapReady()` callback, where I have a helper method that subscribes to the Retrofit Observable and begins polling the api. I then toggle a boolean value in `onPause()`to stop the Observable using `.takeWhile()`. Then, in `onResume()', I toggle the boolean value back on and duplicate the same Observable code from previously. This seems to work alright, but I really dont like that im duplicating code. Hopefully someone knows of a better way.